# A famous dictionary that I bought for me and I gave to my son

Tags: conjunctions, emphasis

That is a famous dictionary. I gave my son it that I had bought for me.

I want to make these sentences into one.

> That is a famous dictionary that I bought for myself and I gave to my son.

Is it suitable ?

Comment: People often over-use the word  _myself_, but here is a case where it _is_ appropriate. "I bought the dictionary for myself."

Comment: Thank you for your pointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combined sentence is correct.  You might consider using "but" instead of "and" (because of the contrast between "bought for myself" / "gave to my son".)

Your initial pair of sentences, in particular "it that I had bought for me." is not so good.